# When to use getSObjectValue in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

We can use getSObjectValue to get field values. But i would like to understand when to use getSObject Value. In a normal wireproperty we can use data.Name or data.Email to get the field value so, in which scenario we should use getSObjectValue.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_schema
You can check the example here

Comment: I checked the documentation, and understand how to use getSObjectValue, but trying to understand "when to use getSObjectValue". Please advise.

Comment: You would typically use this when your LWC is operating against dynamically defined fields rather than hard-coded fields.

Comment: Thanks Phil, Could you please give one example for dynamically defined field vs hard coded field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="ApexStaticSchema" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <template if:true={contact.data}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <p>{contacts.name}</p>
                <p>{contacts.title}</p>
                <p><lightning-formatted-email value={contacts.email}></lightning-formatted-email></p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

In the above code, I gave value like this

```
<p>{contacts.name}</p>
<p>{contacts.title}</p>
```

It is a kind of hardcode. If we use getSObjectValue
we can avoid hardcode. In some cases, we need to avoid the hardcode.

So we can use like this

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="ApexStaticSchema" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <template if:true={contact.data}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <p>{name}</p>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <p><lightning-formatted-email value={email}></lightning-formatted-email></p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
// apexStaticSchema.js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getSObjectValue } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getSingleContact from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getSingleContact';

import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Name';
import TITLE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Title';
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email';

export default class ApexStaticSchema extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getSingleContact) contact;

    get name() {
        return this.contact.data ? getSObjectValue(this.contact.data, NAME_FIELD) : '';
    }
    get title() {
        return this.contact.data ? getSObjectValue(this.contact.data, TITLE_FIELD) : '';
    }
    get email() {
        return this.contact.data ? getSObjectValue(this.contact.data, EMAIL_FIELD) : '';
    }
}
```

```
// ContactController.cls
public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Contact getSingleContact(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Title, Phone, Email, Picture__c FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
    }

}
```

Comment: but in the first example, contacts.name can be stored in a variable in JS side and then can be used in html. this.name = contacts.name; . So, it will be same as the second example

Comment: If you import references to objects and fields, Salesforce verifies that the objects and fields exist , prevents objects and fields from being deleted, and cascades any renamed objects and fields into your component's source code. It also ensures that dependent objects and fields are included in change sets and packages. Importing references to objects and fields ensures that your code works, even when object and field names change.

It is mentioned in salesforce documentation[link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_schema)